# In jq, what's the difference between `.my_array` and `.my_array[]`?

Tags: arrays, jq

I'm new to JQ and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the return types of JQ's filters when applied to arrays.

**Specifically: What's the difference between `.my_array` and `my_array[]`?**

The first example returns an array:

```sh
$ echo '{"my_array":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]}' | jq '.my_array'
[
  {
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2
  }
]
```

While the second example seems to return *each element of the array*:

```sh
$ echo '{"my_array":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]}' | jq '.my_array[]'
{
  "id": 1
}
{
  "id": 2
}
```

What's the precise difference between "filter that returns an array" and "filter that returns each element of the array", and why does JQ consider them different?

Comment: One produces one result per input, while the other may produce zero or more. But you already know this. Do you not know that each filter in a JQ program is repeated as many times as the number of its inputs (e.g. `.my_array | 0` vs. `.my_array[] | 0`), or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Re "*What's the precise difference between "filter that returns an array" and "filter that returns each element of the array"*", huh? The question illustrates this quite well.

Comment: Re "*why does JQ consider them different?*", huh? Why would jq consider `.my_array` and `.my_array[]` the same?

Comment: Seeing as the first question is already answered by the Question, and since the second question makes no sense, I have no idea what you're hoping to get as an answer.

Comment: Can we all chill out a little? I'm new to jq and there's clearly jq-specific vocabulary I'm missing. In particular, I hadn't grokked the concept of "streams" in jq. Mentioning that would be far more helpful than saying "your question is unanswerable". See @peak's helpful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69290384/1004889

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point to understand is that all filters emit a *stream* of zero or more JSON entities. When your first example reads in one JSON object, it places *one* JSON *array* onto its output stream:

```
echo '{"my_array":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]}' | jq '.my_array'
[
  {
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2
  }
]
```

When your second example reads in one JSON object it emits *two* JSON *objects* onto its output stream:

```
$ echo '{"my_array":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]}' | jq '.my_array[]'
{
  "id": 1
}
{
  "id": 2
}
```

A lot of `jq` will make more sense once you understand that filters can be composed together and all filters output streams. The filter `.my_array[]` can be seen as two filters composed together, `.myarray` and `.[]`. We've already seen what `.myarray` does on its own: every time it reads in an object, it places one entity on its output stream, either the value of that field or `null` if it was missing. When the two filters are composed together, each output from the first is fed into the second. Every time `.[]` reads in an array, it places all of that array's contents, one at a time, on its output stream.

Comment: "Stream" was the noun I was missing here. Thank you for your helpful answer!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the key concept you have not grasped is that of a "stream".  jq can be thought of as a stream-oriented language so you might find the following helpful:

https://github.com/pkoppstein/jq/wiki/A-Stream-oriented-Introduction-to-jq

Disclosure: I am the author.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a filter that would do something with the result of each of your two filters. This might make it clearer than simply seeing the value(s) written to standard output.

First, we create an object from the single array value produced by `.my_array`. The entire array becomes the value of the key `x`.

```
% echo '{"my_array":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]}' | jq '{x: .my_array}'
{
  "x": [
    {
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Next, we create *two* objects, one for each object value produced by `.my_array[]`.

```
% echo '{"my_array":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]}' | jq '{x: .my_array[]}'
{
  "x": {
    "id": 1
  }
}
{
  "x": {
    "id": 2
  }
}
```